# function not passing arguments object test

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arguments

I'm currently completing an assignment where I need to pass the following test

```
* should work on an arguments object
```

Here is my code.

```
function first (array, n) {
  var result = [];
  if (Array.isArray(array)) {
    if (n && n > 0) {
      var number = n > array.length ? array.length : n;
      for (var i=0; i < number; i++) {
        result.push(array[i]);
      }
    } else {
      result.push(array[0]);
    }
    return result;
  } else {
    return result;
  }
};
```

Im not sure what lines I need to ammend to make it pass this test, can anyone help me?

Comment: inside a JS function, `arguments` refers to the arguments passed in - in this case, for example, `array` and `arguments[0]` would refer to the same thing ... as would `n` and `arguments[1]` - based on this, the changes should be obvious to you - this assumes that "arguments object" refers to the JS functions `arguments` property - does it?

Comment: alternatively, it could mean that a single object is passed in as arguments ... so maybe declared like `function first(o)` and called like `first({array: [], n: 3})` - is that what is meant in your homework?